# Next.js next.config.js distDir not working

Tags: node.js, next.js

I have a very simple yet very weird problem on Next.js building.

The `next.config.js` file is super simple.

```js
const withPWA = require('next-pwa')

module.exports = withPWA({
  pwa: {
    dest: 'public',
    disable: false,
    register: true,
    scope: '/',
    sw: '/service-worker.js',
  },
  distDir: '.next.build',
})
```

The exactly same config works fine on my old project ("next": "^12.1.0",) but in my current project ("next": "14.0.3",) for some reason it doesn't work. `Doesn't work` means here is that it outputs to the default `.next` directory on `npx next build`, despite of the fact that an other directory `.next.build` is specified.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use internationalization on your project? if so, then you have to add manifest.json and the icons directory to your middleware's ignore directory list. I've faced the same problem with my middleware and fixed it by adding those paths to the ignore directory list.

here's an example of the middleware code portion

```
 export const config = {   matcher: [
 "/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico|Assets|robots|sitemap|icon-*|manifest|path-*).*)",
 ], };
```